# Find the nontrivial proper subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{2}\times \Bbb Z_{2}$.

Tags: group-theory

All i know is that the elements of $\Bbb Z_{2}$ are $\{ 0, 1 \} $. 
Could anyone please explain how to compute the nontrivial proper subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{2} \times \Bbb Z_{2}$. It would be very appreciated.

Comment: What order has $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ and what does that say about the possible orders of subgroups? What is the order of each $g\in\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ and thus also the order of the cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\cong\left\{1,a,b,ab\right\}\;,\;\;\text{with the rule that}\;\;a^2=b^2=1\;,\;\;ab=ba\,.$$

You can also express this group as

$$\left\{(0,0)\,,\,\,(0,1)\,,\,\,(1,0)\,,\,\,(1,1)\right\}$$

with coordinatewise addition modulo $\;2\;$.

And you can also identify this group as a two dimensional vector space over the field $\;\Bbb F_2=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ (what you call $\;\Bbb Z_2\;$ )

Comment: You need to assume $a^2 = b^2 = 1$. Otherwise you get the free abelian group on two generators, i.e. $\mathbb Z^2$. Just saying. =)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, I don't think so since I am giving *the whole group*, not a generating set. Had I written $\;V=\{a,b\;;\;ab=ba\}\;$ then you'd be right.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva could you elaborate more on how the group can also be expressed as {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)} ?

Comment: @Sai82, just write down the element of the **cartesian product** $\;\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio : What if $a^2 = b$? I don't see any inconsistency with the cyclic group of order $4$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, I think you're right. Thanks, editing now.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What are the elements of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \times \mathbb{Z} / 2$? Which of those can form a subgroup? What are the necessary conditions to be a subgroup?

Comment: Well, it would need to contain the identity, (0,0), it would need to be closed under addition modulo 2, and it needs to have inverses.

The only proper, nontrivial one I can think of is {(0,0), (1,1)}.